# Exact phrase search returning non exact hits in cloudsearch

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

We have a CloudSearch index and we are sending the following structured query:

```
(phrase 'revenue management')
```

We were expecting exact phrase matches to be returned, but we are also getting non exact matches like:

```
"...Managing Director..."
```

Is there any way to force exact phrase matches on Cloudsearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should search for an exact match, but you aren't specifying which field you want to search so most likely there's a match in a different field than the one you're looking at. The highlighting in the web console can only show return fields so if the match is found in a non-return-enabled field, you won't see it there. Check the rest of the document and you should find the phrase in there somewhere.

Try restricting your search to a specific field for the phrase search like

`(phrase field=title 'revenue management')`

If that doesn't solve your issue, please post a minimal, complete example of your document and indexing schema, and I'll attempt to reproduce it.

Comment: Yes, you were correct. The problem was that we had so many fields returning that some of them were not shown in the "Run a Test search" screen. Thanks, Alex.